# Modifying seq_along with duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, seq

Any seq Experts here?

I want to count the number of values per id. Counting from 1 to n in the correct order works fine. But duplicated values should be labeld with same number.

Any parameter in for seq that i am missing?

Repr. Ex.: Where "count_n" is the value I actually create, and "need" is the desired output.

Thank you in advance. Cheers

```
Date <- as.Date(c('2006-08-30','2006-08-30','2006-08-23', '2006-09-06', 
'2006-09-13', '2006-09-20'))
ID <- c("x1","x1","x1","X2","X3","x1")
need<- c(2,2,1,1,1,3)
df<-data.frame(ID,Date,need)

df<- df%>% arrange(Date)
df$count_n <- ave(as.numeric(df$Date),df$ID,FUN = seq_along)
```

```
  ID       Date need count_n
1 x1 2006-08-23    1       1
2 x1 2006-08-30    2       2
3 x1 2006-08-30    2       3
4 X2 2006-09-06    1       1
5 X3 2006-09-13    1       1
6 x1 2006-09-20    3       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert `Date` to `factor` for each `ID` which will give you unique value for each `Date`

```
ave(as.integer(df$Date),df$ID,FUN = factor)
#[1] 1 2 2 1 1 3
```

We can also use `dense_rank` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count_n = dense_rank(Date))

#  ID    Date        need count_n
#  <fct> <date>     <dbl>   <int>
#1 x1    2006-08-23     1       1
#2 x1    2006-08-30     2       2
#3 x1    2006-08-30     2       2
#4 X2    2006-09-06     1       1
#5 X3    2006-09-13     1       1
#6 x1    2006-09-20     3       3
```

Comment: This works fine! never thought about this solution. Thank you Ronak!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` on the `sort`ed 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(need = match(Date, sort(unique(Date))))
```